# Custom control example request

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

Does anyone have a good example of creating a WPF custom control or some basic project while using: 1) Dependency Property, 2) Attached Property, 3) Attached Behavior, 4) RegiserRoutedEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at MSDN?

- [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx)
- [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx)
- [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx)
- [Routed Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

Comment: I'd not seen the Control Authoring Overview yet. Thanks.